# MongoDB: Removing an object from one array and appending that in another array in same parent document

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am having a collection storing _id( ObjectId() ), messages(Array of objects) and deleted(array of objects) as shown below:

```
{

   _id: ObjectId("5ea54a39adb83732b057cd12"),

   messages: [
               {
                  msgID: ObjectId("5ea54a39adb83732b057cd89") 
                  msg: "This is a demo message - 1"
               },
               {
                  msgID: ObjectId("5ea54a39adb83732b057ce90") 
                  msg: "This is a demo message - 2"
               },
               {
                  msgID: ObjectId("5ea54a39adb83732b057ce85") 
                  msg: "This is a demo message - 3"
               }
            ],

   deleted: []

}
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to remove an object from messages array according to the msgID and put it in deleted array. What will be the best way to achieve this. e.g. suppose message having mID: ObjectId("5ea54a39adb83732b057ce85") is to be deleted, so the document afterwards should look like:

```
{

   _id: ObjectId("5ea54a39adb83732b057cd12"),

   messages: [
               {
                  msgID: ObjectId("5ea54a39adb83732b057cd89") 
                  msg: "This is a demo message - 1"
               },
               {
                  msgID: ObjectId("5ea54a39adb83732b057ce90") 
                  msg: "This is a demo message - 2"
               }
            ],

   deleted: [
               {
                  msgID: ObjectId("5ea54a39adb83732b057ce85") 
                  msg: "This is a demo message - 3"
               }
            ]

}
```

Note: I am making an application using Node.JS and implementing this so that users can undo there deleted messages over period of time.

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: current latest release : 4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, this is working

```
db.test.update(
    {_id: ObjectId("5ea795db00545a53a435d5be")},
    [{$set:{
        messages:{
            $filter:{
                input:"$messages",
                cond: {$ne : ["$$this.msgID",ObjectId("5ea54a39adb83732b057cd89")]}
            }
        },
        deleted:{$concatArrays:[
            "$deleted",
            [{
            $filter:{
                input:"$messages",
                cond: {$ne : ["$$this.msgID",ObjectId("5ea54a39adb83732b057cd89")]}
            }
        }]
        ]}
    }}]
)
```